# Spring: How to attach SecurityContextHolder on parallel flux

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm using this code:

```java
Map<String, ?> result = Flux.range(1, 2)
    .parallel(2)
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .map(this::mapWithSecurityContextHolder)
    .sequential()
    .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getFirst, Pair::getSecond))
    .block();
```

`mapWithSecurityContextHolder` code is:

```java
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Claims claims = (Claims) authentication.getDetails();
```

So, `authentication` is `null` since flux thread is not request thread and a `NullPointerException` is raised.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in (at least) 2 ways, either with hooks or by putting it on the reactor context. Which basically is a choice between more or less explicit.

(untested, pseudo code, probably want to check if auth is not null etc)

```
Flux.range...
.deferWithContext(ctx -> ctx.<Claims>get("claims")...)
...
.subscriberContext(Context.of("claims",SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails())
.block()
```

for the hooks solution I will point you to [this blog post](http://ttddyy.github.io/mdc-with-webclient-in-webmvc/) where the author uses hooks to set/use MDC context. I've never used it myself but it should work fine too